# Deploy managed services into CloudFoundry

Tags: service, cloud-foundry, managed

I installed Cloud Foundry v2 Nise Installer (with cf-release ea61ec6f8f, VirtualBox)
and successfully pushed 'hello' application with 2 built-in services(mysql and postgresql).

1) How can I add more managed services, e.g. 'echo', 'mongodb' (existing under cf-release/src/services)?

2) I also installed cf_nise_services on the different VM (VirtualBox) but I do not understand how to connect both VMs to deploy services.

I tried to add my service via (on VM1)

```
        create-service-plan/create-plan/create-service-auth-token
```

I got an error after (at the very end)

```
     cf create-service 

     CFoundry::MessageParseError: 1001: Request invalid due to parse error: Decoded JSON cannot be nil

      Or 
         HTTP 404
```

My service does not respond correctly?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The branch ea61ec6f8f is too old and not maintained any longer.
cf_nise_installer_services is, unfortunately, not maintained now. I'll delete it from the README later.
Please try cf-mysql-broker.

Iwasaki Yudai